# Error while compiling c code in opencv on raspbian

Tags: c, opencv, raspbian

I have come across an error during my compilation of c code on opencv in raspbian os. After compilation when give `./contours` an error message is coming

The error message is given below :

> ./contours: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libopencv_gpu.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

please help me in finding my errors.

Comment: post your code.  post your makefile and/or command line compile and link statements.   Is your OpenCV resources/libraries/header files in the correct directories?